# Finding 'break' records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Could you please take a look at teh following task?

I have 'SCHEDULE' table. It has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE (
    EMPLOYEE nvarchar(50),
    SHIFT_START datetime,
    SHIFT_END datetime
)
```

'Schedule' contains data:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEDULE(EMPLOYEE,SHIFT_START,SHIFT_END) VALUES
('EMP01','2017-08-21 09:00:00.000','2017-08-21 12:00:00.000'),
('EMP01','2017-08-21 12:30:00.000','2017-08-21 16:00:00.000'),
('EMP01','2017-08-21 17:00:00.000','2017-08-21 20:00:00.000'),
('EMP02','2017-08-21 09:00:00.000','2017-08-21 12:00:00.000'),
('EMP02','2017-08-21 13:30:00.000','2017-08-21 16:00:00.000'),
('EMP02','2017-08-21 16:30:00.000','2017-08-21 20:00:00.000'),
('EMP03','2017-08-21 09:00:00.000','2017-08-21 12:00:00.000'),
('EMP03','2017-08-21 15:30:00.000','2017-08-21 20:00:00.000')
```

[image]

**Task**:If the difference between shift start date and the previous shift end date for each employee for each date is greater than 1 minute and less than 60 minutes - than add one more row ('Break' row) to existing dataset.

Expected result would be the following:
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: Currently, I do not have own code for it, but I've started to implement it.

Comment: So, what did you need help with, then? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I have some idea's how to do it, but suspect it will not work with good performance. Maybe somebody will give another ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You need the previous value.  In SQL Server 2008, one way uses `apply`.  To get the additional rows:

```
select employee, prev_shift_end, shift_start, 'break' as shift_type
from (select s.*, sprev.shift_end as prev_shift_end
      from schedule s cross apply
           (select top 1 s2.*
            from schedule s2
            where s2.employee = s.employee and
                  s2.shift_start < s.shift_start
            order by s2.shift_start desc
           ) sprev
      ) s
where datediff(minute, prev_shift_end, shift_start) between 1 and 60;
```

You can put `insert` before the logic to insert the rows in the table.

Comment: Any advantage of using cross apply over a using sub query, or is this just a matter of convenience?

Comment: @DavidFreeman Please mark the post as the answer, otherwise it would pop up as unanswered forever.

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . In this case, a matter of convenience.  If you wanted more than one column, then `apply` is more useful.